# KafkaListener headers and payloads order

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, spring-kafka

Here is my code, the question is whether the order of the headers in the list and the order of the messages will match ?

```kotlin
 @KafkaListener(
        topics = ["topic"],
        containerFactory = "kafkaBatchListenerContainerFactory",
    )
    fun receive(
        @Payload messages: List<String?>,
        @Header(KafkaHeaders.RECEIVED_MESSAGE_KEY) keys: List<String>,
    ) {}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes; the index in the list of headers is the same as the index for the corresponding payload.